# Inter-rater reliability with many non-overlapping raters

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I have a data set of 11,000+ distinct items, each of which was classified on a nominal scale by at least 3 different raters on Amazon's [Mechanical Turk](http://mturk.com).

88 different raters provided judgments for the task, and no one rater completed more about 800 judgments. Most provided significantly fewer than that.

My question is this:

I would like to calculate some measure of inter-rater reliability for the ratings, something better than a simply looking at consensus. I believe, however, that Fleiss Kappa, which is the measure I know best, would require a consistent group of raters for the entire set of items, and so I cannot use Fleiss Kappa to check IRR with my data. Is this correct? Is there another method I could use?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Similar questions were asked before with these tags -- have you checked whether a working solution can be found among these?

Comment: Thanks! I sure did check. I only found [one directly relevant question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14691/kendalls-w-for-multiple-objects-and-multiple-surveys), but it has received no answers.

Answer (score 3):

Check out Krippendorff's alpha. It has several advantages over some other measures such as Cohen's Kappa, Fleiss's Kappa, Cronbach's alpha: it is robust to missing data (which I gather is the main concern you have); it is capable of dealing with more than 2 raters; and it can handle different types of scales ( nominal, ordinal, etc.), and it also accounts for chance agreements better than some other measures like Cohen's Kappa.

Calculation of Krippendorff's alpha is supported by several statistical software packages, including R (by the irr package), SPSS, etc.

Below are some relevant papers, that discuss Krippendorff's alpha including its properties and its implementation, and compare it with other measures:

1. Hayes, A. F., & Krippendorff, K. (2007). Answering the call for a standard reliability measure for coding data. Communication Methods and Measures, 1(1), 77-89.
2. Krippendorff, K. (2004). Reliability in Content Analysis: Some Common Misconceptions and Recommendations. Human Communication Research, 30(3), 411-433. doi: 10.1111/j.1468-2958.2004.tb00738.x
3. Chapter 3 in Krippendorff, K. (2013). Content Analysis: An Introduction to Its Methodology (3rd ed.): Sage.

There are some additional technical papers in Krippendorff's [website](http://web.asc.upenn.edu/usr/krippendorff/dogs.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to convince yourself (rather than report a number for another party), you could fit a cross-classified hierarchical/mixed model, with items and raters being two random effects. Then the intraclass correlation for the raters is [variance of the raters' random effect]/[variance of the raters' random effect + variance of the items' random effect + (variance of the logistic distribution = $\pi^2/3$)]. A specific implementation depends on the computational platform you are using; the default on CV is R, so you'd be using `nlme` with it, but you may have something different like SPSS or Stata.